# ThinkPad X1 Carbon Won't Sleep (Automatically + Manually)

Tags: windows, laptop, sleep, power-management

I recently bought a ThinkPad X1 Carbon (Gen 10). I really like this machine.

But since the last couple of days I am facing an issue with it. I can't get my laptop to sleep, neither automatically nor manually.

If I shutdown/restart my laptop, I am able to put it to sleep via the power menu option. It also respects my sleep timeout setting in Windows.

But after an hour (or so) of sleeping the laptop wakes up automatically. After that it won't go to sleep for hours. Even the "Sleep" option in the power menu doesn't work. Clicking on it just turns off the screen, the system stay on.

I have read and followed many documents/blog posts. Nothing seems to work. I know it's the "PDC Task Client: Maintenance Scheduler" that's waking my laptop up. But don't know how to solve this issue. I also don't understand why my system won't sleep when I manually select the sleep option.

Update:

I just used the SleepStudy tool to check what's going on and I saw that Windows is running full memory diagnostics every 1-2 hours. Why would Windows need to run diagnostics so frequently! And it runs for >= 1 hour each time.

[image]

Comment: Please run the Command Prompt as Administrator, use the command `powercfg /energy` and post online the result file (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

Comment: @harrymc: Ah, I got it now.

I just used the `SleepStudy` tool to check what's going on and I saw that Windows is running full memory diagnostics every 1-2 hours. Why would Windows need to run diagnostics so frequently! And it runs for >= 1 hour each time.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Diagnostics do not need to run all the time like this.  I amended my answer to include a Repair Install for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have an X1 9th Generation and it sleeps fine.

**(A) Drivers and Settings:**

Go to Control Panel, Power Options and make sure you are on Balanced Plan. Then Advanced Options and turn off all sleep (suspend) except True Suspend (Hibernation OFF, Hybrid Sleep OFF).

Run Lenovo System Update and update ALL drivers including BIOS. Drivers are very important.

Restart, then do a full shut down.

Start up and test.

If driver updates and settings do not work and then given other new facts (memory diagnostics), then something has gone wrong in the operating system.

**(B) Repair Install, Keep Everthing**

So then the next step here is to do a Windows Repair Install. I assume Windows 11. Important to try Keep Everything as noted below for the first Repair try.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Download.  Run the downloaded file  (double click
> on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB
> Key. Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.   Proceed
> normally answering the prompts.  The default Keep prompt is to Keep
> Everything

.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have those options under advanced power options. Drivers are updated, Windows as well. I have updated the question with new details. Seems like Windows is running full memory diagnostics every 1-2 hours, which lasts for >=1 hour. Not sure why.

Comment: So you just have the Sleep option?  Same here but I turned Hibernation OFF in Windows Setttings - Power.  My machine does not wake up. Look for external influences (mouse, USB) turning on the computer.

Comment: I would be inclined to try a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Media Creation and use the option to Keep Everything.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Comment: I will try the repair option. In the meantime, I found some additional info. I added them as a comment to @DrMoishe Pippik's answer.

Answer (score 0):

@TuhinKarmakar, you've done well so far diagnosing the issue.

Before doing anything, though, you might want to contact Lenovo and the vendor to establish that there is an issue with the new computer, not one you've caused in attempted repairs.

If you *do* want to narrow it down to the most likely culprits, RAM issues or OS issues, try the following:

- Check if there are actual issues with RAM -- certainly possible on a new PC.

  - *Carefully* [reseat RAM](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/Ram-reseating/td-p/3898429), which might be loose. If that fixes the issue, there's no need for the next step.
  - Perform a [full memory test](https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/) (regrettably, this can take many hours).
- If there are no RAM issues, repair the Windows operating system.

  - Use [SFC and DISM](https://winaero.com/how-to-repair-windows-11-with-sfc-and-dism/) to repair Windows automatically.
  - If that does not work, [download the Windows 11 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11/) and create a reinstallation USB with the media creation tool. Use that to reinstall Windows, keeping files. Before doing that, though, **make a complete disk image** so you can go back if files *are* lost.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The RAM is soldered on the board. SFC and DISM didn't find any issue with the system. Next, I will try the repair option. Waiting to a grab a USB thumb drive. I found some additional info. It's not the full memory scan task that's causing the problem by itself. The culprit is the maintenance task that runs every 2 hours. I have set a specific time for the task, but it doesn't respect the timing. I found a temporary remedy, adding a registry key to disabled the task. But now I am worried that not running the maintenance task will cause more damage.